# Iterate through array, sum and put results in new array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, iteration

I have an arrayList filled with integers and I need to iterate through this arrayList, add the numbers up until a threshold is reached, then put the resulting sum into a second arrayList slot, and move back to where I left off in the original arrayList, keep iterating and summing until the threshold is reached and then put that in the second slot, and so on until all 40 original items have been summed and put into a smaller arrayList.

I've thought of using two nested loops but I can't get the two loops to work together.

I'm very new to Java and don't know how to do this. Any suggestions will be helpful.

This is what I have so far:

```
int threshold = 12;
int sumNum = 0;
int j = 0;
int arr1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  while (sumNum <= threshold) {
  sumNum += arr[j];
  j++
}//end while

}//end for
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this with just one loop. You don't need to move back, just stay where you are and keep going on the sum.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> sums(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int threshold){
    ArrayList<Integer> sumArr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int s = 0;  //Sum thus far, for the current sum
    for(int i : arr){
        s += i;             //Add this element to the current sum
        if(s >= threshold){ //If the current sum has reached/exceeded the threshold
            sumArr.add(s);  //Add it to the sumArray, reset the sum to 0.
            s = 0;
        }
    }
    return sumArr;
}
```

You can change the input param from ArrayList to int[] or Integer[] without any trouble whatsoever. Hooray for for-each loops!

Code to use the above:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Integer> i = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //create arraylist 1..20
    for(int x = 1; x <= 20; x++){
        i.add(x);
    }

    System.out.println(sums(i).toString());
}
```

Comment: I'll voucj for this answer.

Comment: Note, this assumes `arr` is an actual `ArrayList`, as opposed to the primitive array provided in the question.

Comment: True, though to quote the first sentence: "I have an arrayList filled with integers..."

Comment: Given the nature of the question, I'd say there may be some confusion.

Comment: Seems likely. That (array vs ArrayList) is a separate question that is very well documented here and elsewhere. In the mean time, the code works either way, just change the type of the first param to suit your fancy.

Comment: This is going to work. I do have an arraylist filled with primitive ints, and there's no confusion as to the difference. I was so buried in this problem for days that I didn't think to use one loop and a running sum, then dump the sum into the new array when the threshold is reached. Thank you Internet!

Comment: Awesome! If you could mark it as correct (click check mark under vote count) so its resolved that would be great

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int threshold = 12;
        int sumNum = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int arr1[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 };
        List myList = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < arr1.length ; i++) {
            sumNum += i;
            if (sumNum >= threshold) {
                myList.add(sumNum);
                sumNum = 0;
            }
        }

        for (int a = 0 ; a < myList.size() ; a++) {
            System.out.println(myList.get(a));
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
15
13
17
21
12
13
14
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
/**
 * Sequentially adds numbers found in the source array until the sum >= threshold.
 * <p/>
 * Stores each threshold sum in a separate array to be returned to the caller
 * <p/>
 * Note that if the last sequence of numbers to be summed does not meet the threshold,
 * no threshold sum will be added to the result array
 * 
 * @param numbersToSum The source number list
 * @param threshold The threshold value that determines when to move on to 
 * the next sequence of numbers to sum
 * 
 * @return An array of the calculated threshold sums
 */

public static Integer[] sumWithThreshold(int[] numbersToSum, int threshold)
{
    List<Integer> thresholdSums = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if (numbersToSum != null)
    {
        int workingSum = 0;

        for (int number: numbersToSum)
        {
            workingSum = workingSum + number;

            if (workingSum >= threshold)
            {
                thresholdSums.add(workingSum);
                workingSum = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return thresholdSums.toArray(new Integer[thresholdSums.size()]);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] testNumbers = 
    {
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
            11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
            21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,
            31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40};

    int[] thresholds = {1, 42, 100, 200};

    for (int threshold: thresholds)
    {
        System.out.println("Threshold sums for threshold = " + threshold + ":\n" + Arrays.toString(sumWithThreshold(testNumbers, threshold)));
    }
}
```

That produces the following output:

```
Threshold sums for threshold = 1:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
Threshold sums for threshold = 42:
[45, 46, 45, 54, 63, 47, 51, 55, 59, 63, 67, 71, 75, 79]
Threshold sums for threshold = 100:
[105, 105, 115, 110, 126, 105, 114]
Threshold sums for threshold = 200:
[210, 225, 231]
```